# mutate() not selecting the variables in the pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

**update**: I got the problem I describe below "solved" by re-installing `tidyverse`, which gave me a warning:

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
> installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of
> Rtools before proceeding:

but did the job anyway. Clearly, this is not optimal, and any light into what may be going on would be greatly appreciated.

---

If it is a silly error, I will delete the post, but I have been making tiny changes, and I can't seem to get this code to run as a chunk. Line by line it does run well.

This is the code, which is from [here](https://github.com/bank-of-england/FanChartsInR/blob/012dea459bd32521c75ab2ec03288ef9e54e01b9/Build_your_own_fanchart.R#L4) and [here](https://bankunderground.co.uk/2019/11/19/build-your-own-fancharts-in-r/):

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(quantmod)
series = c('A191RO1Q156NBEA', 'CPALTT01USQ661S') 
getSymbols('A191RO1Q156NBEA',src='FRED')
getSymbols('CPALTT01USQ661S',src='FRED')
Growth = getSymbols(series[1],src='FRED', auto.assign = F)
CPI = getSymbols(series[2],src='FRED', auto.assign = F)

Data = inner_join(tibble(Date=time(Growth), Growth=coredata(Growth)), 
                  tibble(Date=time(CPI), CPI=coredata(CPI)), by=c("Date")) %>% 
                  mutate(Inflation = 100 * (CPI/lag(CPI,4)-1)) %>% 
                  select(Date, Growth, Inflation) %>% drop_na()
```

The error I get is:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(quantmod)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> getSymbols(series[1],src='FRED')
[1] "A191RO1Q156NBEA"
> getSymbols(series[2],src='FRED')
[1] "CPALTT01USQ661S"
> Growth = getSymbols(series[1],src='FRED', auto.assign = F)
> CPI = getSymbols(series[2],src='FRED', auto.assign = F)
> 
> Data = inner_join(tibble(Date=time(Growth), Growth=coredata(Growth)), 
+                   tibble(Date=time(CPI), CPI=coredata(CPI)), by=c("Date")) |> 
+        mutate(Inflation = 100 * (CPI / lag(CPI,4) - 1)) |> 
+        select(Date, Growth, Inflation) |> 
+        drop_na() 
Error in select(mutate(inner_join(tibble(Date = time(Growth), Growth = coredata(Growth)),  : 
  unused arguments (Date, Growth, Inflation)
```

If I leave out the `select(Date, Growth, Inflation)` line I get the expected columns:

```
> Data = inner_join(tibble(Date=time(Growth), Growth=coredata(Growth)), 
+                   tibble(Date=time(CPI), CPI=coredata(CPI)), by=c("Date")) |> 
+        mutate(Inflation = 100 * (CPI / lag(CPI,4) - 1)) 
> head(Data)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Date       Growth[,"A191RO1Q156NBEA"] CPI[,"CPALTT01USQ661S"] Inflation[,"CPALTT01USQ661S"]
  <date>                          <dbl>                   <dbl>                         <dbl>
1 1960-01-01                        4.9                    12.4                        NA    
2 1960-04-01                        2.1                    12.5                        NA    
3 1960-07-01                        2.5                    12.5                        NA    
4 1960-10-01                        0.9                    12.6                        NA    
5 1961-01-01                       -0.7                    12.6                         1.51 
6 1961-04-01                        1.6                    12.6                         0.868
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have the same problem using the package `dplyr` and trying to run the following example from [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html):

```
starwars %>%
  select(name, mass, species) %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(mass_norm = mass / mean(mass, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` giving the xts object `both`.

```
library(quantmod)
series <- c("A191RO1Q156NBEA", "CPALTT01USQ661S")
syms <- getSymbols(series, src = "FRED", env = e <- new.env())
both <- do.call("merge", mget(syms, e))
```

or with pipes

```
both <- series |> 
  getSymbols(src = "FRED", env = e <- new.env()) |>
  mget(e) |>
  do.call(what = "merge")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am really just trying to learn the "pipe", and would like to know what is wrong in the syntax of the OP.

Comment: Can you see the problem with the original code?

Comment: I got the code from [here](https://github.com/bank-of-england/FanChartsInR/blob/012dea459bd32521c75ab2ec03288ef9e54e01b9/Build_your_own_fanchart.R#L4) and they produce some beautiful fan plots in [here](https://bankunderground.co.uk/2019/11/19/build-your-own-fancharts-in-r/). So I presume there is some explanation why I can't reproduce it unrelated to the data type.

Comment: `plot(scale(both))` or `library(ggplot2);  autoplot(scale(both), facet = NULL)`  Modify as needed.